# Akka-Http: How to use an Actor in a request?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Based on this simple code for Akka-HTTP:

```
val route =
    pathPrefix("myapp") {
      path("search") {
        get {
          //ref ! DoSomething("foo")
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, /* content here from an actor */ ))
        }
      }
    }
```

How can I return a value from an Actor (`sender ! content`) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ask` pattern and map it's return future.

```
import akka.pattern.ask    // enable `?`
import context.dispatcher  // Future's need an execution context, we use the Actor#context's one 

(ref ? DoSomething("foo")).mapTo[ReturningType].map { result =>
  complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, result ))
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: in order to use `ask` pattern one needs to `import akka.pattern.ask` :)

Comment: is there a way to use a "tell" (!)?

Comment: Well, you can extract RequestContext (for example via extractRequestContext directive), pass it to your "ref" actor (in DoSomething object) and there call context.complete(result).

Comment: @Tyth, can you?  I was under impression that the routing tree must be seen as complete by the compiler.  If you tell a message to an actor, what will you return from that part of the routing tree after the tell to let the compiler know that the route will be completed elsewhere?  I was not aware that such a thing existed.

Comment: @cmbaxter, you are right. I guess it was true only for early akka-http/spray versions. We can still use RequestContext in other actor to complete a request, but we have to return RouteResult (via ask pattern) from it to complete a routing tree.

Comment: As an update to this, you can use tell, if you also pass a promise around too - however, it requires some boilerplate, and it gets to the point where you will probably start to think you should just use ask anyway, as it's basically doing the same thing but automatically. This is a real shame in my opinion, as it makes it feel wrong to use actors with Akka HTTP.